# Opensource Storage Options for Kubernetes Cluster running on bare metal

Tags: kubernetes, storage, volume, persistent-storage

I have a 3 node cluster running on bare metal. it was setup using kubeadm.
Each node in the cluster has 100GB disk space, total add up to 300GB.

I would like to utilize the 300GB disk space available on them to run stateful pods like mysql, postgresql, mongodb, cassandra etc. what are the different opensource options available to create persistent volumes.

1. I still havent used kuberentes v1.14 which offers local persistent volumes out of the box. It would be one of the option
2. second option is to run  NFS server on each node and utilize the nfs share from the respective machine to create PV's.

Apart from these what other options can be looked at. please suggest

Comment: https://rook.io/ would be one of good option

Comment: rook.io looks interesting and it uses ceph under the hood. can i have reference url to setup storage cluster using rook

Comment: Here is the quick start guide for it https://github.com/rook/rook/blob/master/Documentation/ceph-quickstart.md

Comment: It use operators to control the lifecycle of the ceph

Comment: can it be used in production?

Comment: Here are the list of ceph users https://ceph.com/users/

Comment: i deployed rook cluster. now how do i create pv that i can use for stateful pods

Comment: It will be the same procedure , have storageclass pvc stuff